# Get distinct values within time chunks

Tags: sql, sqlite, timestamp, distinct, timespan

I have a table with different species and their occurences (timestamp) from field survey:

```
species | timestamp
A       | 2021-04-01T12:35
A       | 2021-04-01T12:36
B       | 2021-04-01T12:36
A       | 2021-04-01T12:37
A       | 2021-04-01T12:39
C       | 2021-04-01T12:40
B       | 2021-04-01T12:42
C       | 2021-04-01T12:44
C       | 2021-04-01T12:44
B       | 2021-04-01T12:47
```

Now I want to count them, not in total but in chunks of 10 minutes each, where only the first occurence is counted.
That means between 12:31 and 12:40 there are species A,B,C. Between 12:41 and 12:50 there are species B,C.

For a single 10 minute chunk I can do something like

```
SELECT DISTINCT(species) 
FROM table
WHERE timestamp IS <condition>
```

But what I need is something like:

```
chunk_start_time | chunk_end_time   | species 
2021-04-01T12:31 | 2021-04-01T12:40 | A       
2021-04-01T12:31 | 2021-04-01T12:40 | B       
2021-04-01T12:31 | 2021-04-01T12:40 | C       
2021-04-01T12:41 | 2021-04-01T12:50 | B       
2021-04-01T12:41 | 2021-04-01T12:50 | C
```

My timestamp has no seconds. That's the reason why it is x1 to x0 minutes.
How can I do the math in SQLite or should I better use Python pandas for that?

Comment: Your expected result does not contain any counting.

Comment: I count every species once.

Comment: This is not counting. Edit your question and explain better what you want.

Comment: I edited the topic, the question is clear.

Comment: As it is, the last chunk for each hour is for example: `2021-04-01T12:51` to `2021-04-01T13:00`. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, I would prefer `2021-04-01T12:50:00` to `2021-04-01T12:59:59`. But my data has no seconds, thats why it is `2021-04-01T12:51` to `2021-04-01T13:00`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use datetime function `strftime()` to produce the chunks:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       strftime(
         '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M', 
         timestamp, 
         '-' || CASE WHEN timestamp LIKE '%0' THEN 9 ELSE SUBSTR(timestamp, -1) - 1 END || ' minute'
       ) chunk_start_time,
       strftime(
         '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M', 
         timestamp, 
         '+' || CASE WHEN timestamp LIKE '%0' THEN 0 ELSE 10 - SUBSTR(timestamp, -1) END || ' minute'
       ) chunk_end_time,
       species
FROM tablename
ORDER BY chunk_start_time, species;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=7fe1918c4722e65f363bfe2dd18cc973).